# Launch a METHOD of an application from another application

Tags: java, android, methods, metadata, launch

I have developed one android application, and now I want to connect it with another one of my own too. When the first one receives a file, launches the second one. In the second one I have a method that can read that kind of file (it's an XML file with some parameters of the first application). The thing is that I know how to launch the app from the main activity, but, can I open it and first launch the read method?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Read about `Intent`. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: I have read about them, and I see that I can launch native apps and open files with another application, but what I want to do is to open my app in the method that can read the file, make it read the file (which is stored in the phone, so I don't have to send it when I launch it) and continue with its flow. Is this even possible?